# Android htmlcleaning

Tags: java, android

I use this code to read an html page, but I've an error....How can I solve this?

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nuovo, PID: 1615
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nuovo/com.example.nuovo.Nuovo_Activity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
```

Code :

```
package com.example.nuovo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties;
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;
import org.htmlcleaner.XPatherException;

import android.util.Log;

public class test {

     public String getRis() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, XPatherException{
          String result="aa";

          Log.d("prova di funzionamento","test");

          CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();

 // set some properties to non-default values
  props.setTranslateSpecialEntities(true);
  props.setTransResCharsToNCR(true);
  props.setOmitComments(true);

  URL url=new URL("https...........aspx");
  Log.d("prova di funzionamentoPost1","test");
 // do parsing
  TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(url);

  Log.d("prova di funzionamentoPost2","test");
Object[] nodes = tagNode.evaluateXPath("//table[@class='TableQuotazioni']");


 TagNode node = (TagNode)nodes[0];

 nodes = node.evaluateXPath("//td");

 Log.d("prova di funzionamento2","test");

 for (int i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {

     String ris= (((TagNode)nodes[i]).getText()).toString();

 result=ris;

 }
 return result;

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can't work with internet in main thread, thats why you have the NetworkOnMainThreadException. Use AsyncTask in order to work with network. Here is a simple example of AsyncTask class.

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {


    myAsyncTask()    {
    }

    // Executed on the UI thread before the
    // time taking task begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    // Executed on a special thread and all your
    // time taking tasks should be inside this method
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Put your work with network here
        return null;
    }

    // Executed on the UI thread after the
    // time taking process is completed
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Update your views here
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}   }
```

For starting task use:

```
MyAsyncTask mTask = new MyAsyncTask();
mTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add PermitNetworks.Class

```
import android.os.StrictMode;

public class PermitNetworks {
    public static final void networkAllPermit() {
         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
         .permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         }
    }
}
```

then add above of all code (thatmeans) http connects

```
PermitNetworks.networkAllPermit();
```

I expect that you well get solve from this.